# How to manipulate push notification message received in WP8 when application is not running

Tags: json, windows-phone-8, push-notification

Our WCF restful service pushes notification to the phone in below mentioned json format

```
{\"Cat\":\"HOL\",\"EX\":\"N\",\"EXT\":\"C\",\"SC\":010,\"SM\":\"ABC\",\"Msg\":\"Hi\"}
```

After receiving this notification I need to have payload to work on json data that is received & extract the message, page to which the application need to redirect after user clicking on the same. Kindly suggest what can be done for the same as for now I'm using the below code but it is not serving my purpose to extract the data

```
pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
```

as it only work when the application is running.
How can I have payload to modify the message when the application is not running and it receive an notification as now it is showing notification with the same json format when I receive the notification which is directly I suppose handled by the OS

Comment: Any1 have an idea how to deal with this particular issue.

Comment: in windowsphone 8 you can't handle this issue ,but if you use windowsphone 8.1 sdk you can achieve it in background by sending raw notification

Answer (score 0):

On windows phone 8, you need to have a background agent (to run when your app is not), the hurdle to jump is that the background agent runs approximately every 30min, so to achieve this I used VOIP to action it. Same concept as how viber, WhatsApp and other services alike use it. The tutorial can be found [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/ChatterBox-VoIP-sample-app-b1e63b8b)

Also it will be also wise to know which push messages you want, a silent one - will only happen on the background, then a normal one which a user will be able to interact with.